# how to set parameter in json in django?

Tags: django

I am newbie to dJango and javascript.

I am trying to pass the variable into the parameter in my function so that the function is called using the variable.

Below are codes.

**view.py**

```
def plot_graph(request,column):
    data = Data.objects.all() \
        .extra(select={'data': connections[Data.objects.db].ops.date_trunc_sql('data', column)}) \
        .values(column)

    return JsonResponse(list(data),safe=False)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^form/$', views.Form),
    url(r'^api/plot_graph/(?P<column>[\w-]+)', views.plot_graph, name='plot_graph'),
]
```

**form.html**

```
var c = {{column_json | safe}}

d3.json("{% url "plot_graph" column=c %}", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d){
    d.c5 = d.c5;
  });
```

What I want to do is that variable `c` is passed into the `d3.json` so that function `plot_graph` is used according to the variable `c`.
However, below code gives me an error saying that 
`Reverse for 'plot_graph' with keyword arguments '{'column': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['index/api/plot_graph/(?P<column>[\\w-]+)']`

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you just add `/$` to you api url like this: `url(r'^api/plot_graph/(?P<column>[\w-]+)/$', views.plot_graph, name='plot_graph'),`. Also just add your value c to the url paramter and not column=c, like: `"{% url "plot_graph" c %}"`

Comment: @ReemaParakh it didn't work for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `c` is a js variable, the context variable `c` does not exist, and the `url` tag is a django template tag, so it expects context variables o base types like `str`, `int`, ect ..

Try:

```
d3.json("{% url "plot_graph" column=column_json|safe %}", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d){
    d.c5 = d.c5;
});
```

You can use context variables and filters inside other tags.

**On the other hand ...**

You have to be sure you have the content you expect in `column_json` or if after apply the `safe` filter there is some useful content.

Comment: I tried it but it gave me below error. `Reverse for 'plot_graph' with keyword arguments '{'column': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['index/api/plot_graph/(?P<column>[0-9]+)$', 'index/api/plot_graph/(?P<column>[\\w-]+)/$']`

Comment: Are you sure you have the content you expect in `column_json` or if after apply the `safe` filter there is some content?

Comment: Yes. I have content in `column_json`. The error message was changed as follows. `Reverse for 'plot_graph' with keyword arguments '{'column': '["c4", "c5"]'}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['index/api/plot_graph/(?P<column>[0-9]+)$', 'index/api/plot_graph/(?P<column>[\\w-]+)/$']`